# Зачем в данной ситуации создавать конструктор и указывать у него throws?

Tags: java

Почему в `public static void main` оператор `throws` пишется в сигнатуре метода, то есть вот так:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("path");
    }
}
```

А если класс без `public static void main`, и я пишу вот так:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Excep {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("path");
}
```

то IDEA подсказывает, что нужно обработать это в конструкции `try, catch` или же оператором `throws`. Я сделал как подсказывала IDEA с оператором `throws`:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Excep {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("path");

    public Excep() throws FileNotFoundException {
    }
}
```

Почему здесь создался конструктор и для него мы написали оператор `throws`?

Comment: "Почему здесь создался конструктор" -
Конструктор у класса есть всегда, даже если вы его не выписали явно, тогда создается конструктор по умолчанию, без параметров и без throws.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

При создании объекта `Excep` произойдёт [несколько действий](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), для вопроса важны два:

- Вызывается конструктор. Если нет явных конструкторов, вызывается конструктор по умолчанию
- В рамках выполнения конструктора происходит инициализация полей объекта. Если инициализация какого-то поля приводит к появлению исключения, то создание объекта прерывается, а исключение пробрасывается "вверх"

Также нужно учитывать, что если вызов метода или конструктора может приводить к пробросу исключения, то это должно быть указано в сигнатуре с помощью `throws ...`

Так как конструктор `Excep` может приводить к появлению `FileNotFoundException`, а конструктор по умолчанию не содержит конструкции `throws ...`, то нужно создать явный конструктор и указать, что его вызов может приводить к возникновению `FileNotFoundException`. Что, собственно, и предлагает среда разработки

---

Чтобы конструктор в данной ситуации не пробрасывал исключение, оно должно обрабатываться в нём. Но в этом случае всё равно придётся создать конструктор (и перенести в него инициализацию `fileInputStream`). И, главное, ловить исключение в конструкторе нужно осознанно тогда, когда это действительно нужно

Comment: Вы прям меня спасаете, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

потому что `fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("path")`будет размещено в конструкторе. Это некий выполняемый код, его же надо где-то разместить так, чтобы он исполнился при создании объекта. И единственное такое место - это конструктор.